# How to create a function in arduino?

Tags: arduino, arduino-c++

I cannot get a function for this code to really work.

```
lastVal = val;                                                             
val = digitalRead(DT);                                                     
if (val == 1 && lastVal == 0)                                             
{
    if (digitalRead(CLK) == 1)                                            
       {
         pos++;                                                           
       }
    else                                                                   
       {
        pos--;                                                              
       }
}
```

Can somebody pleas help me?

Comment: Can you explain better? Is this code inside another function? Are you trying to create a function to put it in? What exactly is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if this is your entire code or not, but in case that is all of the code then I know the reason. Arduino requires the basic setup and loop functions to be referenced in the code, as long as it is referenced you should be fine - you can even leave the inside of the functions empty. You have not really asked the question very well so it is hard to see what you mean.

To create a function you can use this code:

```
void function_name_here(_parameters_here_)
{
   //Code Here
}
```

To reference that function you just declare it by using:

```
function_name_here();
```

By the looks of it you might want to put your code in to the loop function, your code might look like this:

```
int DT = /* Value here */;
int pos = /* Value here */;

void setup()
{
    pinMode(DT, INPUT);
}

void loop()
{
    lastVal = val;                                                             
    val = digitalRead(DT);                                                     
    if (val == 1 && lastVal == 0)                                             
    {
        if (digitalRead(CLK) == 1)                                            
           {
             pos++;                                                           
           }
        else                                                                   
           {
            pos--;                                                              
           }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for help. This waw not my enire code. I have used void setup and void loop

Comment: @N-A Please make sure to post all of your code as it's hard to understand what you mean, also please make sure to edit your post because its also hard to understand what you mean.